meta value in database
in empror theme we have some custom field what I want to add to my custom fields in DOKAN plugin product editor for seller, I added codes in my function.php of theme what dokan said we can used, see my codes::
<?php
// IHXX

/*
* Saving product field data for edit and update
*/
add_action('dokan_new_product_added', 'save_add_product_meta', 10, 2);
add_action('dokan_product_updated', 'save_add_product_meta', 10, 2);

function save_add_product_meta($product_id, $postdata){

    if ( ! dokan_is_user_seller( get_current_user_id() ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $prefix = '_herowp_';
    update_post_meta($product_id, '_herowp_location_google_map', $postdata['_herowp_location_google_map']);

    if (!empty($postdata['feture_group'])) {
        $features = $postdata['feture_group'];

        // Prepare the features data in the desired format
        $formatted_data = array(
            0 => array(
                $prefix . 'feture_title' => 'my title',
                $prefix . 'feture_input' => 'my desc',
                $prefix . 'feture_icon' => 'my icon'
            )
        );

        // Serialize the data before saving to the database
        $serialized_data = serialize($formatted_data);

        // Update the post meta with the serialized data
        update_post_meta($product_id, 'feture_group', $serialized_data);
    }
    
}

/*
* Showing field data on the product edit page
*/
add_action('dokan_product_edit_after_inventory_variants', 'show_on_edit_page', 99, 2);

function show_on_edit_page($post, $post_id) {
    $prefix = '_herowp_';
    // Retrieve values from the database
    $map_embed = get_post_meta($post_id, '_herowp_location_google_map', true);
    
    ?>
        
    <div class="dokan-other-options dokan-edit-row dokan-clearfix ihxx-others">
        <div class="dokan-section-heading" data-togglehandler="dokan_other_options">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>product features</h2>
            <p>optional</p>
            <a href="#" class="dokan-section-toggle">
                <i class="fas fa-sort-down fa-flip-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dokan-clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="dokan-section-content">
            
            <div class="form-field">
                <label class="form-label" for="_herowp_location_google_map"><?php _e('map', 'emperor'); ?></label>
                <textarea name="_herowp_location_google_map" id="_herowp_location_google_map" rows="4" class="dokan-form-control"><?php echo esc_textarea(get_post_meta($post_id, '_herowp_location_google_map', true)); ?></textarea>
                <span class="description"><?php _e('embed code of map.', 'emperor'); ?></span>
            </div>
            
            <?php

            $features = get_post_meta($post_id, 'feture_group', true);
            if (empty($features)) {
                $features = array();
            }

            echo '<h3>' . __('features', 'emperor') . '</h3>';

            foreach ($features as $feature) {
                echo '<div class="feature">';
                echo '<strong>' . esc_html($feature[$prefix . 'feture_title']) . '</strong>: <input type="text" name="feture_group[][0]" value="' . esc_attr($feature[$prefix . 'feture_title']) . '" /><br />';
                echo '<strong>' . __('description', 'emperor') . '</strong>: <input type="text" name="feture_group[][1]" value="' . esc_attr($feature[$prefix . 'feture_input']) . '" /><br />';
                echo '<strong>' . __('icon', 'emperor') . '</strong>: <input type="text" name="feture_group[][2]" value="' . esc_attr($feature[$prefix . 'feture_icon']) . '" /><br />';
                echo '<button class="remove-feature-button">' . __('delete', 'emperor') . '</button>';
                echo '</div>';
            }

            // Button for adding new features
            ?>
            <button id="add-feature-button" class="button"><?php _e('add', 'emperor'); ?></button>
            <div id="feature-forms"></div>

            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $('#add-feature-button').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var featureHtml = '<div class="feature"><strong><?php _e('title', 'emperor'); ?></strong>: <input type="text" name="feture_group[][0]" /><br />'
                            + '<strong><?php _e('description', 'emperor'); ?></strong>: <input type="text" name="feture_group[][1]" /><br />'
                            + '<strong><?php _e('icon', 'emperor'); ?></strong>: <input type="text" name="feture_group[][2]" /><br />'
                            + '<button class="remove-feature-button"><?php _e('delete', 'emperor'); ?></button>'
                            + '</div>';
                        $('#feature-forms').append(featureHtml);
                    });

                    // Event to remove feature
                    $(document).on('click', '.remove-feature-button', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).parent('.feature').remove();
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
}

in theme the function wrote with CMB2::
$courses_group_feture = $courses_metaboxes->add_field(array(
        'id' => 'feture_group',
        'type' => 'group',
        'description' => __('product features', 'emperor'),
        'options' => array(
            'group_title' => __('features', 'emperor'),
            'add_button' => __('add', 'emperor'),
            'remove_button' => __('remove', 'emperor'),
            'sortable' => true,
        ),
    ));

    $courses_metaboxes->add_group_field($courses_group_feture, array(
        'name' => esc_html__('title', 'emperor'),
        'id' => $prefix . 'feture_title',
        'type' => 'text',
    ));

    $courses_metaboxes->add_group_field($courses_group_feture, array(
        'name' => esc_html__('description', 'emperor'),
        'id' => $prefix . 'feture_input',
        'type' => 'text',
    ));

    $courses_metaboxes->add_group_field($courses_group_feture, array(
        'name' => esc_html__('icon (Fontawesome EX: fal fa-user)', 'emperor'),
        'id' => $prefix . 'feture_icon',
        'type' => 'text',
    ));


my code read that fields in DOKAN edito but when I wanna save from DOKAN editor, meta value is not right!
right meta value::
a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:20:"_herowp_feture_title";s:8:"my title";s:20:"_herowp_feture_input";s:7:"my desc";s:19:"_herowp_feture_icon";s:7:"my icon";}i:1;a:3:{s:20:"_herowp_feture_title";s:7:"title 2";s:20:"_herowp_feture_input";s:6:"desc 2";s:19:"_herowp_feture_icon";s:6:"icon 2";}}



what saved::
s:142:"a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:20:"_herowp_feture_title";s:8:"my title";s:20:"_herowp_feture_input";s:7:"my desc";s:19:"_herowp_feture_icon";s:7:"my icon";}}";


I need my update meta value update and data saved right.

You are manually calling serialize, so you must also manually call unserialize on it. That said, because you are storing an array, there shouldn't be any reason to manually serialize it, WordPress should be able to take care of it for you.

This is not a highly expressive question title.
